# What is the verb for the rare, but friendly conversation?

Tags: word-request

Imagine you sit with your friend near the fire. You don't talk much, you mostly drink your tea/smoke/stare at the fire. But sometimes you say a couple of words to your friend, or he/she - to you. You're both fine with that. You enjoy the moment.

What do you call this rare, but friendly communication in a verb?

I thought, ***to have a word*** will do, but that implies some serious conversation, as I've been told. Not what I mean.

***Have a chat*** is not an option, since no chatting take place, just occasional words, and yet you speak to each other, and have some kind of conversation.

Comment: There isn't a word for it, as far as I know. You'd have to describe it in a phrase or two, like "*We hung around the fire, content, with only the occasional comment here and there.*"

Comment: _Rare_ isn't the right word; it implies that you only very occasionally speak to your friend in life, not that you don't talk much on a particular occasion. You could say "We sat, mostly in companionable silence".

Answer (score 1):

No specical term that I can think of.

Informally you could say that you "hung out". This is a very imprecise expression meaning you were together (but it doesn't say what you did).

There are probably lots of multi-word expressions: you "shared some time together" or "relaxed by the fire with each other"

Answer (score 0):

You may say "engaged in laconic persiflage", though it is not a common expression.

> [Laconic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/laconic) (Wiktionary) Using as few words as possible; pithy and
> concise.
>
> [Persiflage](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/persiflage) (Cambridge Dictionary) conversation that is funny and
> not serious.

Here is a link to [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zn-gsp5Gfwk) laconic persiflage. And another link to [BuffaloNews](https://buffalonews.com/news/banter-and-bona-fide-mystery/article_dd369064-5e93-5e57-8344-eb60e9a90bfb.html).

Comment: That is much too over the top.

Comment: Laconic banter maybe? https://swisscows.com/en/web?query=%22laconic+banter%22

Comment: Also, too formal and banter is continuous speech.

Comment: Hmm. Tomorrow I try again.